# What is the maximum value can be given to maximum number of failures in application pool properties in IIS?

Tags: asp.net, iis-7

In my application,application pool is stopped due to series of failures.so i thought of increasing the 'maximum failures' count under 'rapid fail protection'.

I want to assign a big number to 'maximum failures'. What could be the maximum value that can be assigned  to 'maximum  failures' for 'failure interval of 5 minutes'?.

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0):

Int would be the safest bet:  2,147,483,647

But you could just turn off rapid fail protection because you look like you don't want it to occur anyways.